# Hightcharts funnel plot. Labels outside of container are cropped

Tags: javascript, highcharts

My issue is that labels outside of container are cropped. I've set attributes overflow="none" and crop=false but nothing was changed. Label "**emails sent**" is still cropped outside container. Could anyone point me on solution.

You can find my example here: http://jsfiddle.net/d4zGF/540/

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#container')
        .highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'funnel',
                marginLeft:0,
                marginRight: 10,
                marginBottom: 20
            },
            title: {
                text: "Problem with data lables",
                x: -50
            },
            plotOptions: {
                funnel: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        useHTML: true,
                        overflow:"none",
                        crop:false,
                        enabled: true,
                        distance:10,
                        format: '<b>{point.name}</b> ({point.y:,.0f})',
                        color: 'black'
                    },
                    neckWidth: (20/50*0.8+0.2)*100+"%",
                    neckHeight: (20+5)/(50+20+5)*100+"%",
                    width:"100%"
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'emails',
                data: [
                    ['emails sent',   50],
                    ['returns',       20],
                    ['successful', 5]
                ]
            }]
        })
})
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a possibly bug, so I reported it to our developers here https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2564

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, I'm new in Highcharts and thought that it is my mistake.